# why return np.random.normal(10 - 1. / (x + 0.1), 0.5) works

Tags: python, list, numpy, random, parameters

As we can see in the documentation from [numpy.random.normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal)

> numpy.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None) Draw random samples
>   from a normal (Gaussian) distribution.
>
> The probability density function of the normal distribution, first
>   derived by De Moivre and 200 years later by both Gauss and Laplace
>   independently [R217], is often called the bell curve because of its
>   characteristic shape (see the example below).
>
> The normal distributions occurs often in nature. For example, it
>   describes the commonly occurring distribution of samples influenced by
>   a large number of tiny, random disturbances, each with its own unique
>   distribution [R217]. Parameters:
>
> loc : float
>
> Mean (“centre”) of the distribution.
>
> scale : float
>
> Standard deviation (spread or “width”) of the distribution.
>
> size : int or tuple of ints, optional
>
> Output shape. If the given shape is, e.g., (m, n, k), then m * n * k
>   samples are drawn. Default is None, in which case a single value is
>   returned.

Then why `np.random.normal(10 - 1. / (x + 0.1), 0.5)` works when  `x = 10**np.linspace(-2, 0, 8)`

- The parameter loc should be float?
- If this works, what is its meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code draws 8 numbers, each from a different Gaussian distribution. Values of x are taken as distribution parameters but each is used to generate one sample in that distribution.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
np.random.normal(np.zeros(8), 0.5) + 10 - 1. / (x + 0.1)
```

i.e. generating 8 numbers using Normal distribution and shifting them by x.